# Using local OpenStreetMap (*.OSM) map with Openlayers 3?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, offline

What do I need to load a .OSM map in a client side javascript app? (Imagine an offline webapp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With OpenLayers 2 you can load .osm files using [`OpenLayers.Format.OSM`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/OSM-js.html), see the [OpenLayers osm file example](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_osm_file_example) in the OSM wiki. Keep in mind that this approach will be rather limited compared to a tile server and will work only for small files.

With OpenLayers 3 you can achieve something similar according to this [similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26662788/load-osm-file-using-openlayers-3) by using [`ol.source.OSMXML`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.1.1/apidoc/ol.source.OSMXML.html). There is also an [example of loading OSM XML vector data dynamically from a server](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.1/examples/vector-osm.html) (in this case using Overpass API).